# Tag Synonym Request

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Can we create a tag synonym for `synth` and `synthesizer` please?

[I don't have enough rep to propose directly.]

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing -- this is done!

(although, I think merging into [synthesizer](http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthesizer) will suffice for now, since one is a natural typing subset of the other.)